# Fetching Video From YouTube Automatically

Tags: plugins, tags, urls, videos, youtube

I am using WordPress, and a theme called DeTube. Is kind of a YouTube clone, and I use this website to upload mainly videos from YouTube.

Is there anyway to fetch videos and populate all the required fields, name, url, tags, using a plug in. Is there any other method to do this.

Like for example fetching a particular video just by adding it's url?

**Edit**
I found this great plugin called External Videos, it does exactly what i want, but is not interrogated with the theme I am working on, it just fetches the videos and post them as regular posts.

I guess if there is no ready solution, i will have to do the coding by my-self.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic per the [faq].

Comment: Please always show what you've already tried - that's prerequisite to asking a question as it would else be a "do this job for me"-question.

Comment: Sorry did not know, I could not ask about plugins. Is there any place to ask about plugin suggestions here is stackoverflow ?

Comment: Asking for suggestions is mostly not welcome in Stack Exchange. If you want to build a custom solution, research here and in [so]. I've written a couple of things about this and most of what I know I've learned researching the Stack.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the information, I will have that in mind from now on...

Answer (score 1):

Without recommending a plugin, I would suggest looking at a service like IFTTT which allows you to chain API's together.

From the [website](http://ifttt.com):

> IFTTT is a service that lets you create powerful connections with one
>   simple statement 'if this then that'.
>
> Channels are the basic building blocks of IFTTT. Each Channel has its
>   own Triggers and Actions. Some example Channels are: Facebook,
>   Wordpress, Twitter, RSS, GMail, YouTube.
>
> The this part of a Recipe is a Trigger. Some example Triggers are “I’m
>   tagged in a photo on Facebook” or “I check in on Foursquare.”
>
> The that part of a Recipe is an Action. Some example Actions are “send
>   me a text message” or “create a status message on Facebook.” Pieces of
>   data from a Trigger are called Ingredients. For example, the
>   Ingredients of an Email Trigger could be: subject, body, attachment,
>   received date, and the sender’s address.

Recipies can be found [here](https://ifttt.com/recipes).

Comment: What is IFTTT? Can you please provide a link and a summary? So we don't have to google for it and potentially finding something else...